# Cannot find type System.ApplicationException in module mscorlib.dll Error in Windows Store App while using Matlab dll

Tags: c#, matlab, dll, windows-store-apps, mscorlib

I am making an Image processing App for my own use which I don't want to put on store. I want to use my pre designed Matlab codes in that windows store app. When using the dlls in my project, it displays the error -

`Cannot find type System.ApplicationException in module mscorlib.dll`

Comment: Please add code that gives the error

Comment: Right now I don't have written any code; I've just made a simple blank windows store app project and inside references; I've added MWArray.dll and a Matlab dll file for simple add function

Answer (score 0):

Most probable cause for this exception is the DLLs which you are referencing or their dependencies are not supported by WinRT

Try to use `LoadPackagedLibrary` or `GetProcAddress` to load DLLs. If you cannot then Matlab DLL needs to be compiles with WinRT SDK.

Comment: is it allowed to use Matlab dll's inside Windows Store app? Or any way to use them somehow?

Comment: Okey, Thanks let me give it a try :)

Comment: Can you please refer some example in this regard?