# Querying on premises SharePoint 2013 with UWP app

Tags: c#, sharepoint, uwp

I am trying to write an app to enable our users to query Sharepoint and return a document.  I am trying to do this using a UWP app.

I have been reading up on this and there appears to be numerous ways of doing this but I am getting nowhere due to it being a UWP app.

I have just tried to import the dll Microsoft.SharePoint from the SharePoint server into my app an all appears ok.  I can reference it within the app without errors.  This is some test code and obviuosly isnt meant to work but I wanted to make sure `SPSite` was resolved correctly.

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AssetTags
{
    class SPQuery
    {

        private string SPURL;

        public string getSPDocPath()
        {
            SPSite sp = new SPSite(SPURL);

            return "";
        }

    }
}
```

I then debugged the app and it wont run.  It consists of a button on the `MainPage.xaml` as a test.  I get the error -

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Cannot find type System.ApplicationException in module
>   CommonLanguageRuntimeLibrary. AssetTags

After some further googling I came across this question - [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39683977/cannot-find-type-system-applicationexception-in-module-commonlanguageruntimelibr) which states:

> From what I've read System.ApplicationException is depreciated in .Net
>   for UWP and instead you're supposed to just use System.Exception

So my question is does anyone have any experience of developing a Windows 10 UWP app that can query an on premises installation of SharePoint 2013?  If so can you provide some info on how best to get started as I am really struggling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure the DLLs that you import from the SharePoint server are supported in UWP app.

But in UWP, you could use the [Microsoft Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/quick-start). You could see the [SharePoint API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/sharepoint) in Microsoft Graph supports the following core scenarios:

1. Access to SharePoint sites, lists, and drives (document libraries)
2. Read-only support for site resources (no ability to create new sites)
3. Read-write support for lists, listItems, and driveItems
4. Address resources by SharePoint ID, URL, or relative path

Please refer to the [Microsoft Graph Samples for UWP (REST)](https://github.com/microsoftgraph) for more details.